# using other controls as content for transitioning content in mahapps metro

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

can I use only textblock as the only content for transitioning control in mahapps metro. I tried this but it doesn't work as excepted. I am not a wpf expert . Can anyone suggest what is wrong in this? This is what I have tried

```
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    Image imgx  = new Image();
    Image imgy = new Image();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            if (x == 1)
        {
            x = 0;
            tb.Text = "X = 1";
            imgy.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            imgx.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            var uriSource = new Uri("images/blank-cd.png.png", UriKind.Relative);
            imgx.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
            sp.Children.Add(imgx);
            sp.Children.Add(tb);
            SecondcustomTransitioning.Content = sp;
        }
        else if (x == 0)
        {
            x = 1;
            tb.Text = "X = 1";
            imgx.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            imgy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            var uriSource = new Uri("images/placeholder_person.gif", UriKind.Relative);
            imgy.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
            sp.Children.Add(imgy);
            sp.Children.Add(tb);
            SecondcustomTransitioning.Content = sp;
        }
```

Comment: delete all that and use proper XAML.

Comment: @HighCore You mean , a template selector in XAML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mahapps transitioning control is showing only text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764386/mahapps-transitioning-control-is-showing-only-text)